# Add indices to DataGridView headers

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm developing a VSPackage (extension for Visual Studio 2010), and I have a tool window that is hosting a DataGridView control.
I have a very large data-set (e.g. 2D array of size 16384 x 16384) and I update data via VirtualMode.

I want to add index to the row header cells and column header cells,
so I tried:

1. Auto resize via grid methods

   ```
   grid.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(
        DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders);
   ```
2. Iterating through each row

   ```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows) {
      row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
   }
   ```
3. Subscribing to RowsAdded/OnPaint and updating the value there.

**But, all these methods were SUPER SLOW!**

They significantly degraded the rendering of the DGV (takes like ~ 5 seconds or more to render the view after each of these methods, or even worse).

What would you suggest to do instead?

Comment: **DataGridView with 2D array of size 16384 x 16384?** who is going to be able to use that? Suggest you change your design.

Comment: The data is linked to an image/buffer, it displays the values of pixel in each [x,y], sometimes the user is interested in focusing on a specific region in the image, of course the image as a whole is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

I did do initial research into the issue and you've listed all the typical solutions, unfortunately setting 250 million cell values will take some time.

The only thing I didn't see you mention was to fake the header cells (ie first column and row with grey background) and populate them with the source data. Since the DataGridView cell values with be populated with Pixel values one idea is to a append 1 pixel strips to the left and top of each image that you load.

I still think the solution needs a better design. And below are indirect answers to your question.

Make a Picture Dialog with a Zoom-In function. When the user/developer zooms into the pixel level show them the RGB values. Here is [an excellend Drawing Tool example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17893/Extensions-to-DrawTools) written in C# based of MFC CLiDraw and it has an example to show you how to zoom in.

The other idea is a EyeDropper Colour Picker you can get from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36540/Adobe-Eyedropper-Control

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jeremy. These are interesting links and i'll take a closer look to see if I can get something. Regarding your "setting 250 million cell values", I'm not doing it, data is populated on demand (CellValueNeeded event), indices are added on scrolling/data update. Unfortunately, it's still very slow, I suspect the grid is re-drawn way too many times, still can't find the bottleneck.